# Throw of two balls in opposite directions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

Good day community.

I somehow can't wrap my head around this question. And I thought someone could hint me, how to continue solving it.

The questions is: Calculate the Time $t$, when the angle between two in opposite directions horizontally thrown balls is equal to $\alpha=90°$.
The mass is the same $m_1=m_2$ but the starting speeds are different $v_1<v_2$.

Both balls start in virtually the same height and they're both vertically affected by gravity. Also it's in vacuum, therefore is no friction.

I tried to use the dot product $\vec{a}.\vec{b}=\|{\vec{a}\|\|\vec{b}\|\cos({\alpha})}$ to solve for $\cos(90°)$ but thats = 0...[image: Shitty paint illustration of the trajectories]

The only unknown here is the vertical speed, which is dependent on $v_y=g.t$.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to solve it to get an answer in terms of $v_1$,$v_2$ and $g$.
Take the velocity vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ to have horizontal components of $v_1$ and $-v_2$ ( as horizontal components are used in opposite directions) and the vertical components would both be $gt$.

Then try the dot product and you'll find the answer for $t$ in terms of $v_1$, $v_2$ and $g$.